# Convert a String to java.util.Date

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a String as `"2015-12-07"` and I want to convert it to `java.util.Date`. Is it possible? If yes, please tell how. I am using this date to insert into MySQL column of `DATETIME` type using Hibernate.

How property for it in entity class is:

MyEntity.java

```
@Column(name="xyz")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private java.util.Date date;
//setter and getter for date
```

In main I am doing like this:

```
class Test{
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException{
String str="2015-12-07";
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date=sdf.parse(str);
MyEntity me=new MyEntity();
me.setDate(date);
//persisting into db

}
}
```

what happens is code runs fine but nothing is being inserted into column

Comment: There are hundreds if not *thousands* of date parsing questions on Stack Overflow. Please do research before asking a question.

Comment: How are you persisting the `MyEntity`?

Comment: Ok Jon Skeet sir, I will do. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = df.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry my fast typing mistake :D

Answer (score 1):

```
String testDate = "2015-12-07";
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = formatter.parse(testDate);
System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: @Madushan I have already tried this. It is not working while persisting.

Comment: @jcool: If you've already tried it, you should have stated that within the question and given more details than "it is not working".

Comment: *What* is not working? Be specific.

Comment: I have edited my question